# time complexity for binary search trees

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

If I use an insert() function for my bst, the time complexity can be as bad as O(n) and as good as O(log n). I'm assumng that if I had a perfectly balanced tree, the time complexity is log n because I am able to ignore half of the tree every time I go down a "branch". And if my tree is completely unbalanced it would be O(n). Am I correct for thinking this?

Comment: Yaa buddy..you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct, see e.g. wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Searching.

If you use e.g. C++ STL std::map or std::set, you get a red-black, balanced tree. Also worth noting is that with these STL data structures, you get this performance 100% of the time, which can be very important in e.g. hard real-time systems. Hash tables are even faster, but are not fast a 100% of the time like the red-black trees.